# Windows Store Apps: Visual Studio 2012 The system cannot find the path specified error?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I downloaded a sample Windows Store Apps project from the Dev Center samples [site](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CharmFlyout-A-Metro-Flyout-25fe53b6)

When I run the project, I receive the following error in the CharmDemoGridApp

> **The system cannot find the path specified error**

there are no more details, I tried to clean and rebuild the project and nothing happens.
what can be the reason of this ?

Comment: Try after deleting `bin` & `obj` folders from `CharmFlyout\CharmDemoApp\bin`, `CharmFlyout\CharmDemoApp\obj`, `CharmFlyout\CharmFlyoutLibrary\bin` & `CharmFlyout\CharmFlyoutLibrary\obj`

Comment: Thanks for ur help, I did and the problem is still there

Comment: Can you try and find which file is causing the issue? If you look in your solution explorer, one of them should have a (!) in yellow. Maybe make sure that file is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found that the reason was a missing referenced dll.

adding it correctly solved the problem